# Fastest way to split ruby array following a structure

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm looking for the fastest way to split an array into sub-arrays with different size. The size of every array is driven by a configuration file.

Example:

```
c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

My configuration file:

```
block
  contents: 3
  type: ...
  scope ...
block
  contents: 1
  type: ...
  scope ...
block
  contents: 2
  type: ...
  scope ...
block
  contents: 2
  type: ...
  scope ...
```

c.size is equal to the sum of the content number of every block.

I must split my array into 'n' arrays where n is the number of blocks I define in my config file and the size of every array is the number of contents defined in that block.

The result with the given array and config file is:

```
[1,2,3]
[4]
[5,6]
[7.8]
```

Any idea with good performance result?

Comment: Is your config file is an `YAML` file ?

Comment: I plan to use Rails_config gem.

Comment: I need only the split method!

Comment: Roberto, in general you should hold off selecting an answer for awhile, so you you don't discourage other answers.

Comment: @CarySwoveland ok, sorry!

Comment: Roberto, I prefer @Matt's answer and while we were both thinking `shift`--which is not surprising--he did post his answer before mine.  Please reconsider your choice of best answer.

Comment: unless of course @CarySwoveland's is faster; you were going to check performance? Please post results!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight variant of Matt's answer:

If you read the values from the file into:

```
a = [3,1,2,2]
```

you can then do this:

```
a.each_with_object([]) {|e,b| b << c.shift(e)}
  #=> [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

Comment: I will check both for performance!!! :)

Comment: `a` and `c` got flipped in my brain. Thanks, Matt.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
d = [3,1,2,2]

d.map { |n| c.shift n } # => [[1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6], [7, 8]]
```

This destroys the original `c`.